# Install Ubuntu with no access to BIOS and only boot from encrypted harddisk

Tags: boot, system-installation, bios, ms-dos

My laptop (with Windows 7) stopped working and I don't have any recovery disks.
As it is a company laptop I am not able to access the BIOS and it will only boot from harddisk (which does not work).
In a recovery menu I am able to get a Dos prompt. The C and D drive are not accessible. Probably because they are encrypted (PGP).
From Dos I am able to access the CD-rom and the USB-disks.

But the laptop will not boot from CD-rom or USB disk and I am not able to change the boot order as I cannot access the BIOS.
I have also tried to run the Ubuntu installer from Dos but this also does not work.

I would like to run the Ubuntu installer, first install PGP, decrypt my hard disks and recover my files.
After that I want to just install Ubuntu.
If it is not possible to recover my files, then so be it. Then I would just like to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Any reason why you can not enter BIOS? (it being a company laptop is not a reason ;) ).

Comment: @Rinzwind probably administrative BIOS lockout - some laptops can do that nowadays.

Comment: Will company IT recover files for you, or maybe unlock bios in this case? How do you feel about remove the HDD?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! The link in your question has nothing to do with Ubuntu installation. Typo? If so please edit your question to correct it.

Comment: If company has locked BIOS and installs encryption, you should not be modifying system. Some Companies may consider that a major security violation.

Comment: @ThomasW. ok BUT if that is the case he does not OWN the machine. If it is a BIOS password lock those have default passwords that always work.

Comment: @Rinzwind the OP already states it is a company laptop.  That already implies they dont actually own the machine.  The encryption on the system with PGP (Symantec most likely) supports this point.

Comment: @joosthofstede: Did you buy (or receive for free) a company laptop that happens to have a locked out BIOS and a bunch of encrypted hard drives that are/might be broken? If yes, leave a note @ Fabby below.

Answer (score 1):

This question ultimately becomes not a matter of policy within the company you are employed by.

You say this is a company laptop and the BIOS is not accessible (assuming administrative lockout), and the force boot to an encrypted hard drive.

There are two problems you have here then: (1) The company went to some decent (and possibly expensive, if PGP Desktop / Symantec PGp Encryption was used) lengths to encrypt the computer and put administrative lockouts on BIOS to prevent what you are trying to do; and (2) the laptop is not yours and is actually owned by the company.

In the IT Tech Support world these are red flags.  If someone comes to me and says "Hey this is my work laptop and its encrypted can you decrypt the files and give me a copy" I say "No, you don't own the machine.  Have your boss contact me if they want it."  This is a matter of system ownership vs. authorized user - you are an authorized user of the laptop but you are not the *owner* of the machine.

Attempting to bypass the encryption and access your files is almost definitely a breach of the Encryption Policy at your workplace, and a violation of approved terms of use.  Following a method like you request to alter the system like you want would most definitely result in heavy disciplinary action against you.

It is therefore not possible within the scope of this site and within the moral and ethical scope of the Ubuntu community to try as help you bypass the encryption and the BIOS lockouts as you do not own the laptop and because we do not typically assist individuals with bypassing such security measures that are in place.

You need to reach out to your company's IT support staff to have them fix the machine and attempt to recover files.  We cannot as a matter of policy, ethics, morals, and (in some countries, or in the case if some companies) law.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am the only one who knows the password with which the drives are encrypted.
If I would be able to run Ubuntu from a Dos Prompt I could install a PGP client and I would still need the password to access the data.
Another option that would satisfy me is to just run a PGP client from DOS, but that is not something I should be asking the Ubuntu community.
As far as I can see, this is not really a matter of policy, ethics, morals and so on as the drives are encrypted with a password set by me and only known to me.

But it seems running Ubuntu without booting is not an option

Comment: @joosthofstede Do you or do you not own the machine?  If the answer is "my company owns the machine" then it is very likely a breach of policy to install an unauthorized operating system for the purposes of decrypting files.  You may be the only one with passcode access to the machine, but this does not detract from my original answer - there is likely some policy in place regarding the use of and changes to a company-owned system, so you will need to check with your supervisor and the IT staff of your company either way to repair the system.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input.
I will get the data via our IT support and then the laptop can be re-installed.
I was hoping to save me several trips to the office to get this done, but this is how it will be.

My conclusion is that it is not possible to run Ubuntu without rebooting the PC with an installation device (CD, USB, ...). That would have saved me some trouble, but it is what it is.

Thanks for your help and input!